# How can I create a new buffer for the second run of grep, to avoid overwriting the results of the first run of grep?

Tags: buffers, grep

When I run grep by `M-x grep`, I get results in a buffer.

When i run grep again `M-x grep`, the new results overwrite the previous ones in the same buffer.

How can I create a new buffer for the second run of grep, to avoid overwriting the results of the first run of grep?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`M-x rename-buffer`.

Use `M-n` to retrieve the current name, and edit it. E.g., `M-n` puts `*grep*`in the minibuffer. Type `1` to change it to `*grep*1`, etc.

Then just use `M-x grep` again, to have the new search output go to the (new) buffer `*grep*`.

(I bind `rename-buffer` to `C-M-S-<f1>`.)

---

As @JeanPierre pointed out in a comment, you will need to first make another buffer, besides the grep-output buffer, current (or change the mode of that buffer, so that it is not `grep-mode`), before you issue the second `grep` command.

This is because `grep` uses `compilation-buffer-name` to determine which buffer to use, and that function returns the name of the current buffer if the buffer is in the same mode as the command - in this case, `grep-mode`.

If you don't want to change to another buffer manually, you could change to another buffer temporarily as part of a command that wraps `grep`. Or you can set or bind variable `compilation-buffer-name-function` to a function that returns "*grep*".  If that variable is non-nil then its function value is used by `compilation-buffer-name` to determine the name of the buffer to use.

For example:

```el
(defun foo (_mode)
  "Return \"*grep*\" as the name of the buffer to use."
  "*grep*")

(defun my-grep ()
  "`grep`, but always use buffer `*grep*'."
  (interactive)
  (let ((compilation-buffer-name-function  'foo))
    (call-interactively 'grep)))
```

Then you can use command `my-grep` instead of `grep`, even from a buffer that is in mode `grep-mode`.

(I just use `grep` from another buffer.)

Comment: This doesn't work for me if I run the second grep from the just renamed buffer, it will reuse it in this case.  So I have to select the `*grep*` buffer, rename it and go back to another buffer before running grep again.  Same with `emacs -q`.

Comment: How about modifying M-x grep to take a prefix arg and create a new buffer, just like C-u M-x shell? Although the devil is in the details and the details might be devilish...

Comment: @Nick: You can do that by advising `grep` instead of redefining it. But why not just define your own command? All you want to change is the interactive interface, not the behavior of the function `grep` itself.

Comment: @Nick Problem is `grep` already has a use for the prefix arg.

Answer (score 1):

For the same task, I use:

```
(global-set-key "\C-s" 'counsel-grep-or-swiper)
```

Search interactively for what I need, and press <kbd>C-c C-o</kbd> to save the results to a buffer, similarly to how `grep` or `occur` do it.

A new buffer is generated for each <kbd>C-c C-o</kbd>. Each buffer name contains the search string.

Comment: Where is this `counsel-...` command defined?

Comment: `counsel` package on MELPA.